# R : How to concatenate vectors with characters using paste0 and gsub?

Tags: r, paste, gsub

I would like to concatenate  my vector **n** with 2 characters **"0"** and **"m"** .

```
n=c(18,8,13,24,76,81,96,95)
```

I tried :

```
paste0("m", gsub(" ", "0", format(n)))
 [1] "m18" "m08" "m13" "m24" "m76" "m81" "m96" "m95"
```

The expected result :

```
[1] "m018" "m008" "m013" "m024" "m076" "m081" "m096" "m095"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sprintf:

```
n=c(18,8,13,24,76,81,96,95)
paste0("m" , sprintf("%03d",n))
# "m018" "m008" "m013" "m024" "m076" "m081" "m096" "m095"
```

Or simply

```
sprintf("m%03d",n)
```